# Prestashop : trying to add product from admin get blank page

Tags: prestashop

I had tried to add product from admin get blank page after click on save button.

I enabled define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true); but still I dont get any error in admin.

I had also enabled define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);

I get page like screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking through your Apache's `error.log` when that happens?

Comment: where apache error log file located in cpanel host gator ?

Comment: I don't have a clue mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in your controller file if they are containing any white spaces.
It may create a problem on live server.

let me know if it doesn't work.